# SQL Server Subtract Operator Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an "**amount**" field that is of type **varchar(14)**. The goal is to find the net difference between credit and debit amounts. When attempting to cast the credit and debit amounts to decimal so I can sum each, and then subtract the totals to find the difference, I get the following error: "***Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.***"

Please note: I'm able to get the sum(cast(amount as decimal...)) to work independently for both the credits and debit; the issue is with the subtraction operator (-).

Any help would be greatly appreciated (SQL Server 2008).

```
update {table} set amount = 
        (                                                       
            (
            select right('00000000000' + RTRIM(sum(cast(amount as decimal(11,2)))),14) 
            from {table} where debit_credit = 'C'
            )

            -

            (
            select right('00000000000' + RTRIM(sum(cast(amount as decimal(11,2)))),14) 
            from {table6} where debit_credit = 'D'
            )
        )   
            where doc_desc = 'NET_DIFFERENCE';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add zeros to values but simply subtract them and use FORMAT function to add zeros or any formation you want.